# Display data from datagridview vs sql statement, whats proper or more efficient

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

So I am displaying data from an access DB based on which point image is clicked. I have come up with two different ways to do this and I am curious which would be more efficient.

Here are the two different ways I am currently doing this. If you can recommend a better solution I would love to hear about it.

Solution 1 using datagridview which is binded to the access db.

```
private void risk1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pointid.Text = "7";
    int numval = Convert.ToInt32(pointid.Text);
    //To get the correct row
    int id = numval - 1;
    //Point Id of the clicked point
    textBox1.Text = id.ToString();
    pointlbl.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[id].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    //Cat ID of the clicked point
    catId.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[id].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

    webBrowser1.DocumentText = dataGridView1.Rows[id].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
    webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
    using (RichTextBox box = new RichTextBox())
    {
        box.Paste();
        box.Rtf = box.Rtf.Replace("<>", "");
        this.htmlRichTextBox1.Rtf = box.Rtf;
    }

    pointPanel.Visible = true;
    homePanel.Visible = false;
}
```

Solution 2 using a select statement

```
private void risk2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pointid.Text = "2";
    int numval = Convert.ToInt32(pointid.Text);

    //Setup Connection to access db
    string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\braithwaite.mdb";

    //declare Connection, command and other related objects
    OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
    OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

    //try
    //{
    //open connection
    conGet.Open();
    //String correctAnswer;

    cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

    cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Points WHERE point_id = "+numval+"";

    OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();

    reader.Read();
    pointlbl.Text = reader["point"].ToString();
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader["Description"].ToString();
    conGet.Close();
    pointPanel.Visible = true;
    homePanel.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Your application is susceptible to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries. As for efficiency, profile your application. That will give you all the data you need to answer your question.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/getting-data-from-database-and-then-outputing-it-to-the-datagridview

Comment: I understand about using parameters, but I don't understand why that is everyone's first assumption. Would you be able to convert sql to an int value or wouldn't it fail at that point? Otherwise it seems you could inject sql into any text box. This is a windows app used my myself only, I would not be injecting sql to drop or alter tables. This is also just practice values for setting this up. Parameters take more code... But thanks for mentioning that. As far as profile your application I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: But yea I see your point, I should just get in the habit of using parameters and doing it correctly instead of trying to save a few seconds... I will do that from now on.